# Do speakers run on AC or DC?

Tags: ac, dc, speakers

Do speakers run on AC or DC?

I read online that every speaker runs on AC, but I think that is not quite correct.

Comment: It might provide a better answer why you think it's not correct that they run on AC.

Comment: Well i thought that was incorrect because of my project with crystal radio and a amplifier because in cristal radio you need a diode for it to run and there is a problem, with a diode circuit turn DC and runs a speaker WITH DC so thats what confuses me and on a other hand for amplifier to run we need AC signal and it all confuses me

Comment: @Mr.Ananas The detector diode goes before the amplifier, not after it.

Comment: @Mr.Ananas Then you should have asked that question. The diode is used to demodulate audio out of RF, and the audio is AC, we can remove DC before or after amplification.

Comment: You _could_ use pulsed DC on a plain speaker cone (no crossover), relying on the diaphragm's tendency to return to center position to counter the push. This will sound terrible, but could, if biased right, reproduce understandable speech at a low volume.

Comment: @Mr.Ananas - Hi, Here's help for you to make effective use of this Q & A site. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour / https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do speakers run on AC or DC?

At a basic level, a speaker converts an electrical signal into sound. The movement of the speaker cone back and forth produces the sound we hear. The direction and speed of this movement are determined by the electrical signal driving the speaker.

**AC (Alternating Current)**:

- Most audio signals are inherently alternating in nature (i.e., they have a positive and negative phase).
- When you listen to music or voice through speakers, the electrical signals being fed to those speakers **are alternating, causing the speaker cone to move in and out.**
- So, when people say speakers run on AC, they are often referring to the fact that the audio signals being fed to speakers are AC signals.

**DC (Direct Current)**:

- DC is a steady current **that flows in one direction.**
- Applying a constant DC signal to a speaker would push or pull the speaker cone to one side and hold it there. This is not good for the speaker and can potentially damage it. It won't produce a sound you'd want to hear, just a single "thump" if the DC is applied suddenly.
- However, some biasing circuits or advanced speaker designs might utilize DC in certain ways internally, but this is separate from the audio signal itself.

So, while the signals **that drive the movement of the speaker cone** in most typical scenarios are AC, it's not accurate to say that "every speaker runs on AC" because the broader context matters. However, it's critical to note that **you should never apply pure DC to a speaker** as it can cause damage.

Comment: Thanks for an answer

Answer (score 2):

They run on AC and can be damaged by DC.

Answer (score 2):

> with a diode circuit turn DC

No, it doesn't.

You are thinking of a simple power supply, where a diode works with a large value capacitor.  The diode "rectifies" the incoming AC.  That is, because it allows current conduction in one direction only, only the positive half-cycles of the incoming AC are passed to the filter capacitor.  The capacitor is so large that it does not discharge very much between the incoming half-cycles of AC. Because the amplitude of the incoming AC power is almost perfectly constant,  the result is a voltage that represents the peak value of the incoming AC, with a small amount of "ripple", a varying voltage that looks like a small remnant of the incoming AC.

In an AM radio, the diode works with a *small* value capacitor to form a peak detector, similar to the functioning in a power supply.  Because the capacitor value is so small, it can discharge more between the individual cycles of the RF signal.  In this way, it tracks the alternating variations in the RF signal peaks.  One way to think of this is that it is just like the diode and capacitor in a power supply, except that the cap is so small that the resulting ripple voltage is much larger and the DC component is much smaller.  The result is the AC audio signal that Modulated the Amplitude of the RF carrier.  That's where the term Amplitude Modulation comes from.

Comment: This was really helpful thanks!

Comment: It's not that the ripple voltage is much larger, the ripple voltage would be at the RF frequency. The smaller cap reduces the RF frequency ripple but not the low frequency variations in the signal. It's more like a power supply where your mains voltage varies slowly, the voltage at the filter cap will have low ripple but the DC voltage will slowly change.

Answer (score 1):

With a circuit where you're trying to eliminate every last component, and a low enough value of DC, yes, you can run DC through a speaker.

The Phillips EE20 kit I had back in the 1960's used just this sort of economy for some of the circuits, with a high impedance speaker forming the collector load of a single transistor.